# RXJS - multiple consecutive http requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

```
source<http>
  .pipe(
    switchMap(d => this.http.get(d))
      .pipe(
        switchMap(j => this.http.get(j))
      )
  )
  .subscribe()
```

Hello, I need to make 3 http requests consecutively where each call contains data for the next call.. are nested switch maps the best practice for this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to nest them. You can simply chain them:

```
source<http>
  .pipe(
    switchMap(d => this.http.get(d)),
    switchMap(j => this.http.get(j))
  )
  .subscribe()
```

Apart from that, using multiple `switchMap` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

[switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) is better option for consecutive calls.

```
    const first$: Observable<string> = of('first').pipe(tap(c => console.log(c)));
    const second$: Observable<string> = first$.pipe(
      switchMap(first=> {
        return of(first+ ' ' + 'second');
      })
    );
    const third$: Observable<string> = combineLatest(first$, second$).pipe(
      switchMap(([first, second]) => {
        return of(first + second + 'third');
      })
    );

    combineLatest(first$, second$, third$).subscribe(() => {});
```

Comment: So `switchMap` is better than `switchMap`?

Answer (score 0):

Or a more imperative approach in an async method:

```
    const result1: string = await firstValueFrom(this.http.get<string>(url, {headers}));
    const result2: number = await firstValueFrom(this.http.post<number>(url2, result1, {headers}));
    const result3: string = await firstValueFrom(this.http.post<string>(url3, result2, {headers}));
```